# iTextsharp 7: Rotating a Stamp or Annotation

Tags: c#, pdf, rotation, itext7, stamp

A lot of questions I found regarding rotations dealt with Page rotation - and at best, image rotation. How exactly are objects such as Rectangles and stamp annotations rotated via iText?

I initially expected there will be a high level method such as **Rectangle.SetRotation(),** but that did not exist. Attempting to only use **Image.SetRotation (float)** has no effect on the orientation of the stamp - which leads me to believe it's all about rotating the **FormXObject** rectangle.

The stamping code for the sake of context:

```
ImageData img = ImageDataFactory.Create(imgsrc);

float iWidth = img.GetWidth();
float iHeight = img.GetHeight();
if (crop.GetWidth() > crop.GetHeight())
{
    w = crop.GetWidth();
    h = crop.GetHeight();
}
else
{
    w = crop.GetHeight();
    h = crop.GetWidth();
}


//Adjust to Page in Future Code
Rectangle location = new Rectangle(crop.GetLeft(),crop.GetBottom(),iWidth/4,iHeight/4);


PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(location).SetStampName(new PdfName("#Logo"));

PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(iWidth, iHeight));
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj, pdfDoc);
canvas.AddImage(img, 0, 0,iWidth, false);
stamp.SetNormalAppearance(xObj.GetPdfObject());



stamp.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
stamp.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.INVISIBLE);

pdfDoc.GetFirstPage().AddAnnotation(stamp);
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I created the test methods using Java and iText 7 for Java; they should be trivial to port to C# and iText 7 for .Net, though, mainly starting methods with uppercase letters instead of lowercase ones.*

There essentially are two ways to create a stamp annotation whose content appears rotated:

- Set the current transformation matrix inside the appearance stream to rotate everything you add.
- Add a rotation **Matrix** entry to the appearance XObject of the annotation.

#### Using the CTM

As your annotation content only consists of a bitmap image, one can use an `PdfCanvas.addImage` overload which allows setting the CTM for inserting the image:

```
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(ByteStreams.toByteArray(imageStream));
float iWidth = imageData.getWidth();
float iHeight = imageData.getHeight();

Rectangle crop = pdfDocument.getFirstPage().getCropBox();
// The content image of the annotation shall be rotated, so switch width and height
Rectangle location = new Rectangle(crop.getLeft(), crop.getBottom(), iHeight/4, iWidth/4);

PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(location).setStampName(new PdfName("#Logo"));

// The content image in the appearance shall be rotated, so switch width and height
PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(iHeight, iWidth));
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj, pdfDocument);
// Insert image using rotation transformation matrix
canvas.addImage(imageData, 0, iWidth, -iHeight, 0, iHeight, 0);
stamp.setNormalAppearance(xObj.getPdfObject());

stamp.put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.Annot);
stamp.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);

pdfDocument.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(stamp);
```

*([AddRotatedAnnotation](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/annotate/AddRotatedAnnotation.java#L51) test `testRotateImage`)*

#### Using the appearance **Matrix**

This is even more simple than the above:

```
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(ByteStreams.toByteArray(imageStream));
float iWidth = imageData.getWidth();
float iHeight = imageData.getHeight();

Rectangle crop = pdfDocument.getFirstPage().getCropBox();
// The appearance (with the upright image) of the annotation shall be rotated, so switch width and height
Rectangle location = new Rectangle(crop.getLeft(), crop.getBottom(), iHeight/4, iWidth/4);

PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(location).setStampName(new PdfName("#Logo"));

// The content image in the appearance shall be upright, so don't switch width and height
PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(iWidth, iHeight));
// The appearance shall be rotated
xObj.put(PdfName.Matrix, new PdfArray(new int[]{0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0}));
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj, pdfDocument);
// Insert upright image
canvas.addImage(imageData, 0, 0, iWidth, false);
stamp.setNormalAppearance(xObj.getPdfObject());

stamp.put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.Annot);
stamp.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);

pdfDocument.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(stamp);
```

*([AddRotatedAnnotation](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/annotate/AddRotatedAnnotation.java#L96) test `testRotateMatrix`)*

#### Background: the appearance **Matrix**

In a comment you stated

> it works so beautifully with the annotation matrix. If you don't mind, would you care to explain the significance of the Put method?

That `put` call really only adds an entry with key **Matrix** and the given matrix as value to the annotation appearance dictionary.

But this suffices as the PDF specification requires

> The algorithm outlined in this sub-clause shall be used to map from the coordinate system of the appearance XObject (as defined by its **Matrix** entry; see Table 97) to the annotation’s rectangle in default user space:
>
> **Algorithm: Appearance streams**
>
> a) The appearance’s bounding box (specified by its **BBox** entry) shall be transformed, using **Matrix**, to produce a quadrilateral with arbitrary orientation. The transformed appearance box is the smallest upright rectangle that encompasses this quadrilateral.
>
> b) A matrix *A* shall be computed that scales and translates the transformed appearance box to align with the edges of the annotation’s rectangle (specified by the **Rect** entry). *A* maps the lower-left corner (the corner with the smallest *x* and *y* coordinates) and the upper-right corner (the corner with the greatest *x* and *y* coordinates) of the transformed appearance box to the corresponding corners of the annotation’s rectangle.
>
> c) **Matrix** shall be concatenated with *A* to form a matrix *AA* that maps from the appearance’s coordinate system to the annotation’s rectangle in default user space:
>
> *AA* = **Matrix** * *A*

*(ISO 32000-1, section 12.5.5 "Appearance Streams")*

Thus, whenever an annotation with appearance stream is rendered, the appearance is transformed by **Matrix** and the result thereof is squeezed and/or stretched to fit the annotation rectangle.

Comment: very excited to try this out ASAP! I just happened to coincidentally need it urgently in order to correct PDF rotation issues! Thanks as always, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Alright, after some troubleshooting, I managed to fit your code in the context of my program - and I cannot believe that it works so beautifully with the annotation matrix. If you don't mind, would you care to explain the significance of the Put method? I have never used it before, and I can't imagine how else would you apply the rotation operation. I initially thought it simply added it to the annotation dictionary, but what are the consequences of missing out on it?